# How do I convert a string into AltCase?

Tags: java

The instructions are to write a method in which a string is returned in alternating lowercase and uppercase format.  the first letter is uppercase and each subsequent character alternates between lowercase and uppercase.

> Ex: Apple juice -->  ApPlE JuIcE

Here is my code:

```
public String altCase(String text)
{

String newWord ="";

    //make the whole text lowercase

    String textTwo= text.toLowerCase();


    // make every other letter an uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i< textTwo.length(); i++)
    {   
        char letter=textTwo.charAt(i+=2);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(letter))
        {
            char upperLetter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
            newWord+=upperLetter;
        }
        else
        {
            newWord+=textTwo.charAt(i);;

        }

    }
    return newWord;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
My solution:

public String altCase(String text)
{
  StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder(text.length());
  char[] charArr = text.toCharArray();
  for(int i=0; i< charArr.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
          sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(charArr[i]));
      } else {
          sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(charArr[i]));
      }
  } //for
  return sb.toString(); 
}
```